# How to remove separator border row between Columnheader and Data row in listview in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am making a WPF program in VS2017. But I don't know how to remove vertical separator between Columnheader and Data row. 
[image]

I want to remove bottom border of header of above image.

Comment: Code snippet please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like You are talking about this:you need to edit container style, i also commented the Mouse Over and IsPressed  uncomment if you want color change on that states. and also notice background color in style.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates"/>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates"/>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates"/>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="7"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="UpperHighlight" Fill="#FFE3F7FF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,0,0,1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="HeaderHoverBorder" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Margin="1,1,0,0"/>
                        <Border x:Name="HeaderPressBorder" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Margin="1,0,0,1"/>
                    </Grid>                        
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!--
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="HeaderBorder" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderHoverBackground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderHoverBorder" Value="#FF88CBEB"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="HeaderBorder" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderPressBackground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderHoverBorder" Value="#FF95DAF9"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderPressBorder" Value="#FF7A9EB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="#FFBCE4F9"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderContent" Value="1,1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        -->
                        <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <!-- My Edits -->
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.874"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.782"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="Floating">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4082"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Canvas x:Name="PART_FloatingHeaderCanvas">
                                <Rectangle Fill="#FF000000" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" Opacity="0.4697" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="Padding">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Your ListView**

```
<Grid>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle}">
                <GridViewColumn Header="이것이 열 1입니다."  Width="250" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="이것이 열 2입니다."  Width="250" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```